# I created a signin action, and haven't implement so I just want to redirect to login action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an action named 'login' that shows the login form.

The form posts to the 'signin' action.

I haven't implemented the authentication logic yet, so I tried this:

```
def signin

    redirect_to login
  end
```

So when the login form posts, it just redirects back to the login page again.

```
Cannot redirect to nil!
```

but its not working, why?

Comment: what is the difference between a "sign in" and a "log in"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it

```
redirect_to login_url
```

Good for you for trying to build your own authentication system. But if you do eventually plan on going to production, please consider using an established authentication system (such as Devise) unless you REALLY know what you're doing, and know all the security issues like the back of your hand. Get started here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html

Comment: hmm...what is so special about an authentication system?  I'm using a salt for each user password that's incrypted, what else?

Answer (score 0):

Why build the auth from scratch when openid, or basic auth, plugins have already been built?  That's just where I would go with it.